# Access host machine dns from a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

/I'm using docker beta on a mac an have some services set up in `service-a/docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  service-a:
    # ...
    ports:
      - '4000:80'
```

I then set up the following in `/etc/hosts`:

```
::1  service-a.here
127.0.0.1 service-a.here
```

and I've got an `nginx` server running that proxies `service-a.here` to `localhost:4000`.
So on my mac I can just run: `curl http://service-a.here`. This all works nicely.

Now, I'm building another service, `service-b/docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  service-b:
    # ...
    ports:
      - '4001:80'
    environment:
      SERVICE_A_URL: service-a.here
```

`service-b` needs `service-a` for a couple of things:

1. It needs to redirect the user in the browser to the `$SERVICE_A_URL`
2. It needs to perform HTTP requests to `service-a`, also using the `$SERVICE_A_URL`

With this setup, only the redirection (1.) works. HTTP requests (2.) do not work because the `service-b` container
has no notion of `service-a.here` in it's DNS.

I tried adding `service-a.here` using the `add_hosts` configuration variable, but I'm not sore what to set it to. `localhost` will not work of course.

Note that I really want to keep the docker-compose files separate (joining them would not fix my problem by the way) because they both already have a lot of services running inside of them.

Is there a way to have access to the DNS resolving on localhost from inside a docker container, so that for instance `curl service-a.here` will work from inside a container?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'link' instruction in your docker-compose.yml file to automatically resolve the address from your container service-b.

```
service-b:
    image: blabla
    links:
       - service-a:service-a
service-a:
    image: blablabla
```

You will now have a line in the /etc/hosts of you service-b saying:

```
service-a 172.17.0.X
```

And note that service-a will be created before service-b while composing your app. I'm not sure how you can after that specify a special IP but Docker's documentation is pretty well done. Hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: This works! For one `docker-compose.yml` file. Not for multiple `docker-compose.yml`s.

Comment: I guess I'll have to resort to `external_links` then :/